# how to UPDATE SQL database dynamically using python?

Tags: python, sql

```py
import mysql.connector

db = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="1234", passwd="1234", database="books1")

mycursor = db.cursor()

label = '202'
position = 'A1'

sql2 = """INSERT INTO info (label, position) VALUES (%s, %s)"""  
db2 = (label, position)

mycursor.execute(sql2, db2)

print("Updated")
```

When I run code it says updated but whenever I checked and refresh my sql database the old table appears.

How do I update here my latest input data?

Comment: Databases typically don't save changes unless they are _committed_.  You forgot to call `db.commit()`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to commit the transaction.
Add db.commit() after mycursor.execute()